# Is there some way to "spread" object properties to parameters of a function definition?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

Best explained in code:

```
const ROUTE_PARAMS = {
  userId: 'userId',
  companyId: 'companyId',
};

// Is this somehow possible?
// `typeof` is obviously not the right tool here, just used as an example.
function buildRoute(typeof ROUTE_PARAMS): string;

// Result should be similar to:
function buildRoute2(userId: string, companyId: string): string;

//  The function should be called like this:
buildRoute('some-user-id', 'some-company-id');

//  I don't want the function to accept only 1 object like this:
buildRoute({ userId: 'some-user-id', companyId: 'some-company-id' });
```

The idea is to have the route params of `buildRoute` somehow dynamically "bound" to the object.
When defining the function params "manually" (like in `buildRoute2`), I always have to keep them in sync when changing properties of `ROUTE_PARAMS`...

---

**Additional Info**

I'll try to add some information as my question above does not seem to be sufficiently clear:

- I'm explicitly looking for a way to "type" this function from an **object** like the one shown above (`ROUTE_PARAMS`).
- I can't change this to some other structure (tuple type, some kind of array, ...) as that would require refactoring of other parts in my code which work with the object `ROUTE_PARAMS`.
- The function should except each object property as a single input parameter (i.e. function arity === number of object properties).
  I **don't** want the function to accept all properties packed into 1 object ( &  examples above).

Comment: This not exactly what you asked for, but you can use object destructuring like this: `function buildRoute({userId, companyId}: typeof ROUTE_PARAMS): string;`

Comment: @coglialoro Yep, I was aware of that but am looking for a way so that the function takes all properties as individual parameters instead of only taking 1 object.

Comment: The one thing I can't figure out from your question is: How do you intend to call this function? Is the only important thing for you that you can pass the arguments one by one? Should the number of arguments equal the amount of properties in the object?

Comment: I'm also not getting it. Why not just pass the object as a whole? I don't understand the rationale you posted under your code snippet.

Comment: @MikeS. Yes, I'd like to pass the arguments one by one and yes, the number of arguments should be equal to the amount of properties in the object. Why I don't want to change the function to accept 1 object instead is part of some "overall API design" and explaining that would go beyond the scope of this question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At first, I thought what you want would be easily possible by using the spread operator with a tuple type. For instance,

```
function f(...args: [string, string]) {}
```

is (except of the parameter names) the same as

```
function f(arg0: string, arg1: string) {}
```

So we could try:

```
const ROUTE_PARAMS = {
  userId: 'userId',
  companyId: 'companyId',
};

function buildRoute(...args: typeof ROUTE_PARAMS[keyof typeof ROUTE_PARAMS][]): void {}
```

However, `typeof ROUTE_PARAMS[keyof typeof ROUTE_PARAMS][]` is an array, so that we could supply an arbitrary number of arguments to the resulting `buildRoute` function. It would be effectively the same as when you wrote  `function buildRoute(...args: string[])`. Also, when the values are not only `string`s, but, for instance, a `number` was included, the inferred type would be `(string | number)[]` and we could supply a `number` at *any* position.

The difference to `f` above is that the type of the spread variable is a *tuple* for `f` but an *array* for `buildRoute`. So we would need to get a tuple out of the values of `ROUTE_PARAMS`. But, unfortunately, that is not supported and will not be, as a corresponding proposal was declined: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13298.

So I now think that what you want is probably not possible with TypeScript.

Comment: An alternative is to declare `ROUTE_PARAMS` as a tuple: `type ROUTE_PARAMS = [ userId: string, companyId: string ];`. Yes, it means it's not an object (or a concrete thing) any more but it would be the correct thing to express parameters as OP seems to wish. I don't really know why OP wants to start with an object, however - it seems a bit like [an XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: @VLAZ: Yes, I had the same impression on first glance, but I think there are valid reasons for the OP's wish. In particular, he might need `ROUTE_PARAMS` as a variable at some place and does not want to declare the essentially same type "twice".

Comment: @Remirror s guess is correct that I need the "starting variable" `ROUTE_PARAMS` as a variable of type object in other places and can't easily refactor it to something like the mentioned tuple `[ userId: string, companyId: string ]` without having to refactor other code as well which I'd like to prevent (at least for now).

Answer (score 2):

#### Updated Answer:

As mentioned in [Remirrors answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72025937/10956902) spreading function arguments to a specific set of properties and types on a variable is not supported. Remirrors answer explains well why this is the case.

However, just to extend on Remirrors answer to make the syntax a bit cleaner you can create a global type that uses a generic. This can then be reused in all the places you need without having to rewrite the long keyof code repeatedly:

```
// Re-useable type
export type TypeFromVar<T> = T[keyof T][];


const ROUTE_PARAMS = {
  userId: 'userId',
  companyId: 'companyId',
};

const User = {
  name: 'Reece',
  age: 25,
  isVerified: true,
}


function buildRoute(...routes: TypeFromVar<typeof ROUTE_PARAMS>) {
  const [userId, companyId] = args;
  // do something
}

function otherFunction(...person: TypeFromVar<typeof User>) {
  const [name, age, isVerified] = args;
  // do something
}


buildRoute("userId1", "companyId2"); // only accepts string parameters

otherFunction("John", 36, false); // accepts string, number and boolean parameters
```

#### Original Answer:

Alternatively, **if you can define array types for your variables** you can get the exact number of arguments and their types by doing it like this:

```
type RouteParams = [
  userId: string,
  companyId: string,
]

function buildRoute(...routes: RouteParams): string {
  const [userId, companyId] = routes;
  // do something
}


buildRoute("user1", "company2")
```

Comment: Yes, but note that `ROUTE_PARAMS` in the OP's question is a variable, not a type. To get your `RouteParams` type out of it, you would need the -to-tuple-functionality I mentioned in my answer, which probably does not exist.

Comment: Perhaps I have misunderstood the question, but from my understanding the OP was trying to define the arguments of a function call so they could be called one by one, as oppose to having to pass in an object (based on the  and  examples), and that the variable was just an example to demonstrate the invalid typeof syntax. 

Probably needs more clarification from OP.

Comment: I've explicitly written `... The idea is to have the route params of buildRoute somehow dynamically "bound" to the object.  ...`, so yes, I'm having the **object** `ROUTE_PARAMS` as my "starting point" and don't want to (cannot) change that to a tuple type ATM.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Apologies for the misunderstanding, I have updated my answer with a suggestion on syntax and a reference to Remirror's explanation.